# Why does linking different MSVC Run-Time Libraries crash in release mode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ffmpeg, runtime, msvcrt

I am using ffmpeg and Qt to build a small demo app.

- FFmpeg is built with `/MT` (crossbuild or built with visual 2010)
- Qt is always built with `/MD`
- My little example is always built with `/MD`

When the application

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    av_gcd (75, 25);

    return a.exec();
}

//note : following is av_gcd source in ffmpeg libs:
int64_t av_gcd(int64_t a, int64_t b)
{
    if (b)
        return av_gcd(b, a % b);
    else
        return a;
}
```

is executed in **release mode it crashes because it doesn't see `av_gcd` as executable memory**. The error is:

> First-chance exception at **0x0000000300905a4d** in mylittleexample.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation at location **0x0000000300905a4d**.
>
> =======================================
>   VERIFIER STOP 0000000000000650: pid 0x1B9C: **Attempt to execute code in
>   non-executable memory (first chance).**
>
> **0000000300905A4D** : Address being accessed. 
>  **0000000300905A4D** : Code
>   performing invalid access. 
>    00000000009FF770 : Exception record. Use
>   .exr to display it. 
>   00000000009FF280 : Context record. Use .cxr to
>   display it.
>
> =======================================

The address `0x0000000300905a4d` doesnt change regardless of the function in the library (ffmpeg in this case), or the compiler used for the executable (vs2010, vs2012) or a different machine.

If I use the FFmpeg built with `/MD` and it works as one would expect.

1. I observe that the executable doesnt load the library when the
   library is compiled with `/MT`. Why is that?
2. Furthermore, If the library is compiled with `/MT` and debug
   information is enabled when the **application** is linked (`/DEBUG`
   param to the linker) then the library is loaded and everything
   execute correctly. Why?